# Android proguard rule for databinding

Tags: android, proguard, android-databinding, android-r8

I have used onclick databinding in my layout files

```
 <data>

        <variable
            name="clickHandler"
            type="com.example.ui.ClickHandler" />
 </data>

<TextView
        android:onClick="@{(v)-> clickHandler.onClick(v)}"/>   <!-- used it like this -->
```

My interface file

```
package com.example.ui

import android.view.View

interface ClickHandler {
    fun onClick(view: View)
}
```

Whenever i try to build the project i get following error

Expected field or method name at D:\Second Repo\app\build\intermediates\aapt_proguard_file\release\aapt_rules.txt:480:33
-keepclassmembers class * { *** @{(v)-> clickHandler.onClick(v)}(android.view.View); }
^

Answer (score 0):

AAPT2 expects a method name for the `android:onClick` attribute, and will generate keep rules based on that assumption.

See https://issuetracker.google.com/296914102.